# Making method call on abstract generic class variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, generics, abstract

Honestly i have a hard time with this problem.
Let's say we have a base class:

```
public abstract class Work {
}
```

And two realizations:

```
public class SimpleWork extends Work {
    }

public class HardWork extends Work {
    }
```

Now i want abstract work executer with generic type of work:

```
public abstract class AbstractWorkExecuter<TWork extends Work> {

    public abstract WorkResult executeWork(TWork work);
}
```

And two realizations of executers:

```
public class SimpleWorkExecuter extends AbstractWorkExecuter<SimpleWork> {
    
        public abstract WorkResult executeWork(SimpleWork work);
    }

public class HardWorkExecuter extends AbstractWorkExecuter<HarkWork> {
    
        public abstract WorkResult executeWork(HardWork work);
    }
```

Then i need to create some factory to get realization of executer that i need:

```
public class WorkExecutorFactory {
    public static AbstractWorkExecuter<?> create(String type) {
        if (type.equals("simple")) {
            return new SimpleWorkExecuter();
        } else {
            return new HardWorkExecuter();
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to use all of this:

```
public static void main (String args []) {
    Work work = new SimpleWork();

    //This line works fine
    AbstractWorkExecuter<?> workExecuter = WorkExecutorFactory.create("simple");
    //There is the problem
    workExecuter.executeWork(work);     
}
```

The last line in Eclipse show me exception like this:

```
The method executeWork(capture#2-of ?) in the type AbstractWorkExecuter<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Work)
```

So, what should i do to make it work? I want to avoid using raw types. Need a mention that i don't know what realization i may need and the real project have much more realizations then two in this example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this with a string. You need to pass in something with more type information, so you can know you get back a `AbstractWorkExecuter<SimpleWork>` for that argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a string. There isn't enough static type information to be able to ensure the type correctness at compile time.

Create factories that give you back an instance of the type you want. For example:

```
class WorkExecutorFactory<T> {
  private final Supplier<T> supplier;

  private WorkExecutorFactory(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  T create() { return supplier.get(); }

  static final WorkExecutorFactory<SimpleWork> SIMPLE_FACTORY = new WorkExecutorFactory<>(SimpleWorkExecuter::new);
}
```

Then you can use `SIMPLE_FACTORY.create()` (which carries the type information of the thing it creates) instead of `WorkExecutorFactory.create("simple")`.

Comment: It is not correct, in fact, the name is not even necessary.

Comment: @josejuan I don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: _"You can't do this with a string. There isn't enough type information."_ I say you can and the information is there.

Comment: @josejuan sounds like you should write your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

@Aleks, your approach is correct and in general is all about dependency injection, very extense subject.

Your problem does not require define the executor to use at all. Only using types and reflection Java can match, instantiate and run every work.

```
public class Test {

    // the core team define some basic names
    interface Work {}
    interface WorkExecutor<T extends Work> {
        default void executeWork(T work) {
            System.out.printf("%s run %s%n", this.getClass().getName(), work.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    // some dev team create simple works
    static class SimpleWork implements Work {}

    // some dev team create hard works
    static class HardWork implements Work {}

    // some dev team create simple executors
    static class SimpleWorkExecutor implements WorkExecutor<SimpleWork> { }

    // some dev team create hard executors
    static class HardWorkExecutor implements WorkExecutor<HardWork> { }

    // (extra requirement) some dev team create aditional (sidecars) hard executors
    static class SideCarHardWorkExecutor implements WorkExecutor<HardWork> { }


    @SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String... args) {

        // somewhere somebody define works
        List<Work> works = asList(new SimpleWork(), new HardWork());

        // for each work to do
        for(Work w: works) {

            final String validExecutorType = WorkExecutor.class.getName() + "<" + w.getClass().getName() + ">";

            // find all available workers, simply ensure the jar, class, ... are loaded (websphere, jboss, java -jar...)
            // NOTE: reflection could be hard, use a good reflection dependency injection library!
            for (Class<?> clazz : Test.class.getDeclaredClasses())
                if(Arrays.stream(clazz.getGenericInterfaces()).map(Type::getTypeName).anyMatch(validExecutorType::equals)) {
                    ((WorkExecutor<?>) clazz.newInstance()).executeWork(cast(w));
                    // you can break or continue doing the work with other available worker executors
                }

        }

    }

    private static <T extends Work> T cast(Work w) {
        return (T) w;
    }

}
```

with output

```
Test$SimpleWorkExecutor run Test$SimpleWork
Test$SideCarHardWorkExecutor run Test$HardWork
Test$HardWorkExecutor run Test$HardWork
```

only include/place the classes and the matching will be automatic.

Note: the foor loop body is specific of the DI library used, learn about that and practice before use in real projects.